# Laravel 8 Websocket Pusher error: auth_key should be a valid app key

Tags: laravel, apache, laravel-8

i m using laravel 8.83,
I've followed every step in tutorial to use laravel websocket. Still getting Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastException
Pusher error: auth_key should be a valid app key.
here is my .env

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

PUSHER_APP_ID=testappid
PUSHER_APP_KEY=123456
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=testappsecret
PUSHER_HOST=localhost
PUSHER_PORT=6001
PUSHER_SCHEME=http
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

Comment: php artisan key:generate

Comment: doesnt work, it should be somethink about PUSHER_APP_KEY ...

Comment: Yep, this is about PUSHER_APP_KEY. Maybe `php artisan config:clear` help. But this is api exception, and i think you try to work with real pusher with test creditinals